# Lithium PHP: Large body in PUT not getting into request object

Tags: php, rest, put, lithium

We have a REST service built off of Lithium in PHP. Recently, I was building a PUT endpoint. I noticed an issue when I would try to PUT a large body to this service.

Here is the interesting part. In the index.php file, I do this to verify the data is hitting the service correctly:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
error_log('DATA: '.print_r($data, 1));
```

This prints out the PUT body as I expect it to. However, when we get to this point in the index.php file:

```
echo \lithium\action\Dispatcher::run(new \lithium\action\Request);
```

The request object's data field is EMPTY. 
Note that this works perfectly with a smaller body, it when I hit a certain threshold that it fails.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Have you checked your PHP max post/upload settings?